# Variations price adjust based on previous variation

Tags: commerce

Using Drupal Commerce, is there a way to adjust the variation price base on the first or second variation selected?

For example I have 3 variations: size, material, color. If I choose Small (that costs $5) and material that costs $10 ($15 total), then when I choose Large at $12, the material should cost $20.

I guess I should use rules. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations - here you can read about product variations, don't forget to enable field as an attribute field that can change the Add to Cart form

After that you need to create products for all variations with right prices. You can use http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc

Comment: THank you, i will look into that. So what you are saying is then actually if i have 2 variations that change each others price, i need to combine them to make 1 variation because the system is not capable up updating an attribute/variation based on another attribute/variation?
Similar question from someone else i found: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/automatic-product-variations-pricing

Comment: yup, you were right, ended up doing with taxonomy terms and have to create oh so many items. got another good explanation here http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/7894/adjust-variation-price-based-next-variation#comment-7566