# Load a variation (or Line Item) based a previous choice

Tags: commerce

I asked this similar question already ([Variations price adjust based on previous variation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71367/drupal-commerce-variations-price-adjust-based-on-previous-variation)), but I am thinking to make the solution more 'base'.

Is there a way to 'load' different fields based on a selection of a previous field?

If I select 'Size: Medium', I want to load those colors and styles that have a different price than 'Size: Small' has.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [COMMERCE OPTION](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_option) module with [COMMERCE PRODUCT ATTRIBUTES](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes) to explore the possibility of achieving this. Go through by documentation for using it properly & I hope you will have fun in achieving what you want...

Comment: THanks, I have been looking over these cant seem to get it. I think basically what i want is 2 select lists and the second has to change based on the first ones selection. running a topic here to http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/7894/adjust-variation-price-based-next-variation#comment-7540

Answer (score 0):

My answer for the next guy searching here...

I figured this out by using taxonomy terms (categories in commerce kickstart), and then yes, indeed, make a product for each combination. (ive heard bulk product creation can do this, and incase you are dealing with a customer input size (how many inches long do you want it), then check out custom line items and Pricing rules.

Thread on drupal commerce > http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/7894/adjust-variation-price-based-next-variation#comment-7566