# Adding a form to a product drupal commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

I just want to add a form to a product and after I check the services in that form the amount increases. image of the page in the Picture the product price is 7$ but when I add the service it added 10$ then the amount become 17$. any solution for this?

[image: page product]

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for product variations. [Here](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations) are the official docs.

> Product attributes are the descriptors we use to define kinds of
>   products. For example, we could describe a tshirt by the color and
>   size. These attributes mean that in the real physical world your store
>   may only carry one red shirt, but you have three sizes or three
>   "variations." Commerce software must deal with product variations in a
>   flexible way. Here's how Drupal Commerce abstracts it:
>
> **Product Types**. A product type is a specific bundle based on a custom
>   product entity. Each bundle can have fields attached to it, including
>   pictures and other kinds of information.<
>
> **Product "Informational"
>   Fields**. Any field on a product can be a simple "informational" field.
>   Typical informational fields include an image of that specific
>   configuration of a product. For example, if you sell a tshirt with a
>   cool print in multiple colors, each product with a different color
>   could have an image field that, when displayed on the product display
>   node, will change when you select different attributes (like color).
>
> **Product "Attribute" Fields.** Any field on a product type with a defined
>   list of options (list of text options, list of taxonomy terms, list of
>   colors). The attribute fields are special because of the way they turn
>   into selection widgets on a product display. Often you will pair an
>   attribute field (like a color dropdown) with an information field
>   (like an image field) to let the user "select" the blue tshirt and the
>   Drupal Commerce system will quickly load the picture associated with
>   the blue product.
>
> **Product Displays.** If needed at all, these are
>   groupings of products. You can reference any type and number of
>   products on a product display. In order to make use of product
>   displays, we recommend only showing one type of product per product
>   display. The product display is where you typically see the product
>   with drop downs to "configure" or "order" the right kind of product.

For the different pricing of the variations refeer here: [Automatic product variations pricing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/automatic-product-variations-pricing).